# Create a query based on invoice table to show a 15% increase on tax in a new column

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
ALTER  TABLE invoice
ADD  INV_INCREASE_TAX FLOAT;
```

Above query successful add a new column to the invoice table. Then after I need to show 15% increase value of `'INV_TAX'` column value set to the newly created `'INV_INCREASE_TAX'` column.

```
UPDATE invoice 
SET INV_INCREASE_TAX = INV_TAX * 1.15 
WHERE INV_INCREASE_TAX IS NULL;
```

I got this error when i execute this query;

**Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.   0.000 sec**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INV_INCREASE_TAX` is not a key column, i.e. it is not part of an index. That's why the `where` check kicks in. If you think you know what you are doing and the tool is limiting you then switch that behavior off as told by the error message (see the Workbench preferences).